# Can I add a void to Type with Code

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a Compiler codes in my form Like this

```
Assembly BuildAssembly(string code)
        {

            List<string> SKParams = new List<string>();
            string Caption = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\";
            SKParams.Add(Caption + "System" + ".dll");
            SKParams.Add(Caption + "System.Windows.Forms" + ".dll");
            SKParams.Add(Caption + "System.Data" + ".dll");
            SKParams.Add(Caption + "System.Core" + ".dll");
            SKParams.Add(Caption + "System.Drawing" + ".dll");
            SKParams.Add(Caption + "System.Drawing" + ".dll");
            SKParams.Add(@"D:\SK\Projelerim\ZxProject\MySDK\MySDK\bin\Debug\MySDK.dll");
            SKParams.Add(Caption + "System.XML" + ".dll");
            Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            ICodeCompiler compiler = provider.CreateCompiler();
            CompilerParameters compilerparams = new CompilerParameters(SKParams.ToArray());

            compilerparams.GenerateExecutable = false;
            compilerparams.GenerateInMemory = true;

            CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerparams, code);
            if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder("Compiler Errors :\r\n");
                foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
                {
                    errors.AppendFormat("Line {0},{1}\t: {2}\n",
                           error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorText);
                    MessageBox.Show(error.ErrorText);
                }
                throw new Exception(errors.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                return results.CompiledAssembly;
            }

        }
```

I am getting assembly with this MEthod from string code.Now I want to add a void this assemble and change the assembly and source code (string code) How can I Make this?

Comment: It's not so clear (at least to me) what you are trying to do. Do you mean that you create an Assembly with your method passing it a string (code) which defines a class, and after that you want to add a void method (which was not in the original code) to that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know for adding methods to an existing type is using the DynamicMethod class that you find in System.Reflection.Emit. You can get some help and an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx, but it is not too user friendly. If you want to create this method starting from a string, you have to parse the string and translate it in a series of calls to Emit with the appropriate OpCodes. I think that you could much more easily recreate your assembly with the updated/added code.

If you should have to apply the newly added method to an existing instance of your class, I would create the new assembly, create a new instance of the new class and then copy the old values for the properties via reflection.